# RSA Encryption - Generates string with '\n' chars and I cannot decrypted

Tags: java, android, rsa, public-key-encryption

I am trying to create a simple utility class in java to encrypt a String using a RSA public key, but my code generates an encrypted String with some '\n' chars and cannot be decrypted in the server.

This is my code:

```
private static String ALGORITHM = "RSA";
private static String TRANSFORMATION = "RSA/None/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding";

private String encryptData(String txt, SecurityCallback callback) {
        String encoded = "";
        byte[] encrypted = null;
        try {
            String publicKeyContent = getPublicKeyString();
            PublicKey pubKey = stringToPublicKey(publicKeyContent);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
            encrypted = cipher.doFinal(txt.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            encoded = Base64.encodeToString(encrypted, Base64.DEFAULT);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            callback.onError(exception);
        }
        return encoded;
    }

private String getPublicKeyString() {
        return PUBLIC_KEY.replaceAll("\\n", "").replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----", "").replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
    }

private PublicKey stringToPublicKey(String stringKey) throws InvalidKeySpecException,
            NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        byte[] keyBytes = Base64.decode(stringKey, Base64.DEFAULT);
        X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        return keyFactory.generatePublic(spec);
    }
```

My public key is in the format

-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
hasdjasjkfhajdhjahskdfjhasjkfhajkfhkaj
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

Comment: Your program runs with my own sample RSA public key and gives an output "EQi7OCpoUvAgV9LGbYql2qSHOUe1lwLo6S6vFVZM9wLY60aRTtl1ih5WPYFVpueXIIOEBNL9qsCN
IfZETSf4Ba2WqQlQ37+nWx/eigN+MEJc4byHyeM4GQeA4eMW2j+P2W0y/esQAawTfIqfVnrnv0U8
ZSulyEfpnBFBTMyXjJfdGnPYtDaQyIWUTR79RcLrfllpgsIU+nG+mLkMich7HqKZ8diGsepqKYrt
mRsnR/dOQkpjuY+PTJhK6eIN6rKHrk92Zxt1CZLj5Yq+Bv9vBTm8GAALSfl44L1u9+Tqv8piwhGW
IenKTvzfO85Ed0Tp8COAFDTYXfWVgYU5U2aqJg==", so where is your problem? BTW: you need to use the Bouncy Castle library to get this to work.

Comment: If you are in doubt whether you are creating a meaningful ciphertext you should post an example (test key pair, plaintext, Base64 encoded ciphertext). If the server cannot decrypt your ciphertext you should verify that your public key matches the server's private key and that the same padding is used on both sides (especially OAEP is a bit tricky regarding the digests used, different providers, e.g. BouncyCastle vs SunJCE, use different defaults).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that using that code in Android was generating an encrypted text with some end of line chars and the backend was giving an error when trying to convert the String. So I fixed it by replacing those end of lines chars.

Not sure why those chars are added during the encryption process.